# List and use the variables defined inside my own function

Tags: python, function

Suppose that I have a function like this one:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

    return c
```

Now can I use the `a`, `b`variables? Even if `foo()` is not returning them like this?

```
foo().a + foo().b
```

I know this is easy to do if `foo` was a `class`, but it's not.

Comment: If they're not `global`, and they aren't `return`ed, they *cease to exist* when the function exits.

Comment: can you provide a bit more information about your objective? What are you "allowed" to tweak in this code? Can you add arguments? Can you return a,b along with c? Are you the one who is implementing this function?

Comment: What do you intend to do by this? The point of function-locals is that they are local to the function.

Comment: I will never understand why people try so hard to work around the *deliberate* flow control and scoping rules of languages.

Comment: The function is defined in another file, returning just one variable. I want to check the variables that are not returned by this function from another file.

Comment: @igorkf Can you modify the function? Or is it part of some library/assignment code or something like that?

Comment: It looks like implementing a `callable` class that doubles a function via its `__call__()` method is a very clear way to achieve what you want. But that means you will have alter the code you are showing. Are you ok with that?

Comment: @kyriakosSt how would you do that?

Comment: I am writing an answer atm

Comment: probably because you have not explained clearly what the constraints on your question are. Using globals, returning them or changing to a class are all arguably accepted ways to achieve what you want, but people are not sure why they do not meet your requirements. Don't get me wrong, you could have very valid reasons for not wanting to make those changes, but more information on what "we are allowed to do" would help. Otherwise, without modifying anything, the tl;dr answer is you can't use those variables.

Comment: Be aware that accessing function locals may need inspection, bytecode analysis, refactoring or other means. Each requires some work to demonstrate and which one, if any, is appropriate highly depends on the restrictions. Please describe your requirements and restrictions *as closely as possible* to allow people to efficiently help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are saying you have a function, not a class, python is able to transcend those differences using callable classes. Those are normal classes whose instances can be called as normal functions while still maintaining an internal state. Here is a demonstration:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self.b = self.c = None

    def __call__(self): 
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
        return self.c

foo = Foo()
print(foo()) # will print 3
print(foo.a) # will print 1
print(foo.b) # will print 2
```

In the above code snippet, you can think of `Foo` as a class that generates objects (int this case `foo`), each being a function. Your code can call `foo()` and what this will do, is execute the `__call__()` method of that class. Since however `__call__()` uses `self.a`, `self.b`, `self.c` instead of local variables `a`, `b`, `c`, their values after the execution of the function will be saved inside the `foo` object. So you can check them just by doing `foo.a` and so on.

If you would like to add more arguments in your original `foo()` function, simply add them to the `__call__()` method and assign values to them when calling `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try function attributes. We know that everything in python is an object. So you can define attributes for a function also since a function is also an object. If you want to use a local function variable outside the function, then it is better to make those variables as the function attributes.

I tried something like below :

```
def foo():
    foo.a = 1 # function attribute
    foo.b = 2 # function attribute
    c = 3

    return c

foo()
print(foo.a + foo.b) # -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use them like that.You can return all 3 variables and use them accordingly.
Try:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    return a,b,c

a,b,c = foo()
```

Alternatively you can create function variables as below.

```
def foo():
    foo.a = 1
    foo.b = 2
    foo.c = 3

foo()
print(foo.a, foo.b, foo.c)
```